# Error with DSN while using in SSIS?

Tags: mysql, ssis, dsn

Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'MySQL Connector.root'.
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (System.Data)

---

Program Location:

```
   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLFreeStmt(OdbcStatementHandle StatementHandle, STMT Option)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.FreeStatement(STMT stmt)
   at System.Data.Odbc.CMDWrapper.FreeStatementHandle(STMT stmt)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Close(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcMetaDataFactory.GetTablesCollection(String[] restrictions, OdbcConnection connection, Boolean isTables)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcMetaDataFactory.PrepareCollection(String collectionName, String[] restrictions, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbMetaDataFactory.GetSchema(DbConnection connection, String collectionName, String[] restrictions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.GetSchema(DbConnectionFactory factory, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnection outerConnection, String collectionName, String[] restrictions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.GetSchema(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.OdbcSchema.GetSchema(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.DataSourceConnection.GetSchemaTable(DataTable& dataTable, String collectionName, String[] restrictions)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.DataSourceConnection.ConvertGetSchema(DataTable& dataTable, Guid schemaEnum, Object[] restrictions)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.DataSourceConnection.GetSchemaTable(DataTable& dataTable, Guid schemaEnum, Object[] restrictions)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.ComboBoxWithTables.GetTableInfos(DataSourceConnection dataSourceConnection, String connectionName)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.ComboBoxWithTables.FillTableOrViewComboBox()
```

Any Idea to solve this? Connection is fine as test connection shows connected but while runtime this is happening.